# Can the lifespan of a returning temporary variable be extentended by using move/swap c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a tree which base node is (not all methods are shown):

```
struct node_base {
    node_base(): _size(0),_parent(NULL) { }
    virtual ~node_base() {}

    virtual node_iterator_base& begin() const =0;
    virtual node_iterator_base& end()  const=0;

protected:
    size_t _size;
    node_base* _parent;
};
```

From that abstract class you can derive child classes which implement the needed container to hold all child nodes.
As seen I also have a custom iterator node_iterator_base

```
struct node_iterator_base {
    virtual ~node_iterator_base() {}
    virtual node_iterator_base& operator++()=0;
    virtual node_base* operator->() const =0;
    virtual node_base& operator*() const =0;
    virtual bool operator==(const node_iterator_base& x) const =0;
    virtual bool operator!=(const node_iterator_base& x) const =0;
};
template<It>
struct derived_iterator: public node_iterator_base {
    derived_iterator(It I): ci(I) { }
    ...
    It ci;
}
```

The idea behind these base classes and their derived classes is to make it able to write something like this:

```
derived_node n;
for(node_iterator_base it=n.begin(); it!=n.end(); it++) {
    do_something(*it);
}
```

Now the problem is to implement begin in the derived class

```
node_iterator_base& derived_node::begin() const {
    return derived_iterator(container); 
    //This will not work because a temporary variable is passed to a 
    reference
}
```

What can be done instead? If we change the declaration of begin to

```
virtual node_iterator_base begin() const =0;
```

and

```
node_iterator_base derived_node::begin() {
    return derived_iterator(container); 
   //This will not work either because node_iterator_base is an abstract struct
}
```

Of course I could return a pointer but then my iterator will not look like a STL iterator and will have to destroy it manually.
How can I return a reference? Can move/swap from C++11 help me?
More about my heterogeneous tree here
https://www.facebook.com/A-smart-tree-and-a-simple-parser-i-c-1678796648883396

Comment: Your iterator might have a pointer on polymorphic object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.  You cannot do what you want.

The medium answer is yes.  You can use the `pImpl` pattern to pass a facade which holds a pointer to an interface within it; it forwards calls to its implementation interface (pImpl).  This permits a seeming value type like an iterator to be polymorphic, at the cost of dynamic allocation and indirection.

The longer answer is that you are attempting to type erase iteration by type erasing iterators.  You can do this with pImpl, or something like any or even std function.  However, the iterator interface of C++ has a large surface and is interacted with frequently during iteration.  Type erasure of iterators has proven expensive.  Boost has any iterators that have rolled this for you; they are not suited for use in performance sensitive code.

It may be better to type erase iteration operation itself instead of the iterators.  You iterate far less often than you interact with an iterator; by type erasing the less frequent operation you can improve performance significantly (or really, waste less).

Finally, consider using variant instead; if you can enumerate the subclasses, you could use that to give the compiler less indirection and more information.

Any and variant are available in boost or C++17 or can be reimplemented yourself.

Comment: I think you are right but what is "to type erase iteration"?

Comment: @user `foreach_chicken( [&](auto&& chicken) { chicken.pluck(); } );`; because you can expose more control flow (say, work on buffers of chickens not single chickens) you can reduce the frequency of type erasure while iterating.